# how to enable onclick when fancybox is closed

Tags: javascript, html, video, fancybox

```
<video controls="controls" width="640" preload="none" poster="{_file.F_FILE_THUMB_IMAGE}" id="{_file.U_PLAYER_ID}" onclick="this.play();this.onclick=null;" />
```

I am trying to use the above to make a video play when fancybox is opened. At the moment it does this but when I close fancybox then reopen it the video doesn't play again due to the this.onclick=null; part

without this.onclick=null;, every time I click a video that is playing, the onclick interferes with it, eg. the video will not pause when clicking on the pause button.

I need the onclick="this.play(); so that the videos play on Android devices. Otherwise when fancybox pops up it refuses to play the video at all.

autoplay in the video tag is not an option as all videos are hidden in divs and there are multiple on a page so all it does is make them all play when a page loads.

I am stuck with this and need some help, anybody got an idea on how to get around this?

Comment: try changing onclick="this.play();this.onclick=null;" to onclick="this.play();"

Comment: I tried already with just onclick="this.play()" as I have said above, it works in getting Android to play the video, but it interferes with Firefox. Everytime I click on the fancybox video it triggers the onclick and keeps the video going without pausing. If I try to press the pause button it is the same deal, the video won't pause because it is being asked to play with the onclick.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to write longer javascript functions to manage toggle between pause, play etc. Or you can Greg's solution.

Comment: the thing is that no matter what I do it seems to keep interfering with the video player controls. the onclick:this.play() gets triggered on everything I press on the controls since it is part of the video tag, including volume slider and mute. Gregs solution isn't working for me either.

Comment: Hmm, then maybe you should start looking for video player plugins, I'm not sure about the situation and it's too late for me now. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Thanks for your help xFortyFourx. I was able to get Greg's method to work with a few small changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the fancybox, you should add an onClosed event handler with a function to reset the onclick event.

```
$("#exemple").fancybox({
    'onClosed' : function() {
        $("#example").attr('onclick',"this.play();this.onclick=null;");
    } 
});
```

Comment: Although this looks like exactly what I am after, it doesn't seem to want to add the onclick attribute. Also the callback is called 'afterClose' now according to [fancyapps](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

Comment: I'm not sure why it didn't work the first time but now it does. Thankyou so much mate.

Comment: I had to use 'beforeLoad' instead of 'afterClose' btw. I also needed to have the onclick hardcoded in the video tag otherwise it took two loads of Fancybox for the video to play on Android, like it wasn't being added soon enough. So the hardcoded onclick took care of the first load, and your method on top of that made the onclick event usable again after being made null.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
onclick="this.play();this.onclick=null;"
```

TO

```
onclick="this.play();this.onclick=null;"  
//OR
onclick="this.play(); return false;"
```

Comment: onclick="this.play(); return false;" is working somewhat, probably the best so far. The only downfall is that all controls on the video now do nothing except for the volume slider. Mute, pause/play don't work at all while the video is playing.
Thanks for persisting with this btw.